# Use gradle to run the touch command on a file

Tags: gradle, touch

I have a build.gradle file that runs a series of tasks before building my android APK. I looked through the documentation but I didn't find an answer so I'll ask here. Is it possible - and if it is how - to run the touch command on a file using gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a task of type `Exec` and pass appropriate configuration. See the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) Is there anyway I can do this just using groovy or java rather than using a command line function?

Comment: You need to create the file or just set the last modified date? If You need to create file, just use `new File()`, otherwise refer to file using `project.file('somefile')` and modify the date with `setLastModified` method.

Comment: Its for a build procedure so I just need to update the time stamp of the file. Ill give the project.file method a try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

It has been some time since this question was answered.
I think there is a more elegant way available in Gradle as of today.

Remembering that Gradle treats Ant as a first class citizen, you can invoke any ant task as a simple method call using Groovy syntax.

Ant has a touch task and in Gradle you can invoke it easily as shown below. 
For reference on the parameters supported by the Ant Touch task look here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html

```
task testStuff(){
   ant.touch(file:"some.properties")
}
```